# how login/register from any page in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and I want to login/register from any page in my application and not to be require to load `domain.com/login` or `domain.com/register` for that.

PS: I'm using default authentication `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy the form content of login/Register page and paste it in your laravel page.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('email') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autofocus>

                                @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                                @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                    <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @endif
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                                <div class="checkbox">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : ''}}> Remember Me
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Login
                                </button>

                                <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                                    Forgot Your Password?
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: so no need to change any route or something?

Comment: Yes. just copy and paste the form in your laravel page. reminder dont change the input name and action="{{ url('/login') }}" of the form